# How to expose to the user the values of an object B within an object A as an attribute of object A?

Tags: python, design-patterns

An object A instantiates an object B as b = B. B stores a list of values, but also some methods related to the creation and manipulation of such values. The methods of B should be used in A, but only by the object internally, not directly by the user that interacts with A. The values of B, however, should be accessible to the user.

How would I implement this in Python?

2 ideas occur to me that I seem dirty to me.

1. write a getter Method for b that returns b.values (I do not like that because then b does no longer return the construction signature or alike)
2. store B in a variable _b and then store _b.values in b (I do not like that because it is kind of redundancy)

Are there other solutions that I did not think about? Letting the user use b.values is no option because from the perspective of the user b is just data and he/she should not be confronted with the complexity of B.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Teach me this programming paradigm” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: It is a design question not something that you find in the documentation. Yes of cause I can find things like `__str__` or `__repr__`. But this does not help here. Furthermore, the fact that I did evaluate 2 solutions by my own shows that I tried something on my own. It is just that I think both solutions are not very good. Thus I have to admit I find your statement unjustified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) to expose the B values through A, but make the B field [private](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables) of A.

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.__b = b  # make it private

    @property
    def b_values(self):
        return self.__b.values

    def print_summary(self):
        print(f"the B values are : {self.__b.values}")
        print(f"the sum is {self.__b.sum()}")
        print(f"is it empty ? {'yes' if self.__b.is_empty() else 'no'}")


class B:
    def __init__(self, values):
        self.values = values

    def sum(self):
        return sum(self.values)

    def is_empty(self):
        return len(self.values) == 0


a = A(B([1, 2, 3]))
print(f"values are {a.b_values}")
a.print_summary()
```

works fine :

```
values are [1, 2, 3]
the B values are : [1, 2, 3]
the sum is 6
is it empty ? no
```

and you cannot access the methods on B from outside A :

```
>>> a.__b.is_empty
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute '__b'
```

Comment: Thank you. I see now why it was interpreted as a "reading the documentation" issue before, though sometimes being pushed into the right direction helps as in this case. It is possible to look up the documentation in a strategic way if you already have the conceptual knowledge. I think the critique of the question underestimated that. Thx. for taking the time despite this critique.